# Image processing-Shape Recognition

Tags: image-processing, shapes

I want algorithm for recognizing multiple no of shapes(Specially rectangle and squares) in a picture.Preferably I am using C# so, I am looking forward for solutions in C#.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm, an implementation of an algorithm or a library that helps implementing such an algorithm?

Comment: That would be Hough Transform, Egon pointed you to a C# implementation that uses that

Comment: I think Hough transform is too much (in terms of complexity and also has a bad efficiency) for what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

check aforgenet....
http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library that does a lot of image processing for you there is always [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). I think it is is c++ though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Circularity algorithm as a first approach, which is very easy to compute:

C = p<sup>2</sup>/a where `p` is the perimeter (border area) and `a` is shape area.

To know how to read/write pixels quickly, take a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx)

Alternatively look for shape signature algorithm  available at Rafael Gonzales book. In this algorithm you compute the center of the object using central momentum, the you compute the distance between the center and each border pixel. You'll end up with a 1D signal where peaks represent bigger distance from the center. In a square, you have 4 symmetric peaks while in a rectangle 2 big peaks and 2 smaller ones.